# Invalid form when uploading a file

Tags: django

I am trying a basic example in uploading a file with django.
I tried the code from the [django documentaion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/) but I keep getting invalid form. And when I don't test the validation of the form and try to handle the file directly, I get:

> MultiValueDictKeyError at /neurons/nblast
>   "
>   'file'"

P.S:
Previously, I had used a model with a FileField and set the (upload_to), but in my current case I don't need to use the model, I only need to let the user uploads his files.

This is my code:

### Template

```
<body>    
<form action="" method="post">

    {{ form }}
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-success" name="btn_upload">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span>
        <b>Upload</b>
    </button>

    {% csrf_token %}
</form>      
</body>
```

### Views

```
def test(request):
    if request.method == GET:
        form = UploadFileForm()

    if request.method == POST:
        if 'btn_upload' in request.POST:                
            form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)                
            if form.is_valid():                   
                handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            else:
                print 'Not Valid'

        form = UploadFileForm()

    return render_to_response('test.html',
                              {'form': form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

### Forms:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Just a guess: have you tried looking at https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/ especially the enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute?

Comment: Yea that's the problem !! Thanks :D
I didn't noticed this

Comment: Cool, could you please accept my answer below so I get the points? Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried looking at [The Django 'File Uploads' docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads) , especially the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute?

Answer (score -1):

u missed this one enctype="multipart/form-data"